# replace property with hashmap values javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an array like this:

```
a1=[
    {
        "Domain": "xyz",
        "Classification": "prod",
        "AnnualData": [
            {
                "Year": 2029,
                "Value": 67007.41
            },
            {
                "Year": 2030,
                "Value": 163234.6
            },
            {
                "Year": 2031,
                "Value": 166388.91
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "Domain": "xyz",
        "Classification": "prod",
        "AnnualData": [
            {
                "Year": 2029,
                "Value": 67007.41
            },
            {
                "Year": 2030,
                "Value": 163234.6
            },
            {
                "Year": 2031,
                "Value": 166388.91
            }
        ]
    }
];
```

I want to replace AnnualData , so that o/p look like

```
[
    {
        "2029": 67007.41,
        "2030": 163234.6,
        "2031": 166388.91,
        "Domain": "xyz",
        "Classification": "prod"
    },
    {
        "2029": 67007.41,
        "2030": 163234.6,
        "2031": 166388.91,
        "Domain": "xyz",
        "Classification": "prod"
    }
]
```

how would we do this?

I hava converted the annualdata into hashmap using list.reduce((obj, item) => ({...obj, [item.Year]: item.Value}), {});and tried to push it into main array but dint get the expected results

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You don't use `push()` to modify an object. You can use `Object.assign()` to merge objects in place, or reassign using spread notation.

```js
a1.forEach(obj => {
  let annualData = Object.fromEntries(obj.AnnualData.map(({Year, Value}) => [Year, Value]));
  delete obj.AnnualData;
  Object.assign(obj, annualData);
});

console.log(a1);
```

```html
<script>
let a1=[
    {
        "Domain": "xyz",
        "Classification": "prod",
        "AnnualData": [
            {
                "Year": 2029,
                "Value": 67007.41
            },
            {
                "Year": 2030,
                "Value": 163234.6
            },
            {
                "Year": 2031,
                "Value": 166388.91
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "Domain": "xyz",
        "Classification": "prod",
        "AnnualData": [
            {
                "Year": 2029,
                "Value": 67007.41
            },
            {
                "Year": 2030,
                "Value": 163234.6
            },
            {
                "Year": 2031,
                "Value": 166388.91
            }
        ]
    }
];
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would have done it using forEach method, like this :

```
let result = a1.map(item => {
    // new object
    let newData = {};
    // loop over your data
    item.AnnualData.forEach(data => {
        // set each year as a key in newData, with the number as value
        newData[data.Year] = data.Value;
    });
    // fill the other properties
    newData.Domain = item.Domain;
    newData.Classification = item.Classification;
    return newData;
});
```

The principe is to create a new objet, and iterate over your data to fill the new object resulting as what you want.